# Discord.js awaitMessages returns nothing and blocks the code

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Here is my code:

```
try {
    var collectedMessages = await msg.author.dmChannel.awaitMessages(true, { time: 30000, max: 1, errors: ['time'] });
} catch (e) {
    msg.author.send("Looks like you took too long to reply!");
};
```

And it doesn't react to messages and doesn't timeout. I'm on v13.3.1

Comment: What version of discord.js are you on? Why did you put `true` as the first argument?

Comment: Because its in DM so the author will always be correct, the version is ^13.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments are invalid. In v13, only the `options` argument is present. Change it to this:

```js
await msg.author.dmChannel.awaitMessages({ 
    time: 30000,
    max: 1,
    errors: ['time'],
    filter: () => true // I wouldn't recommend this but it's what you want
})
```

Comment: Thanks finally works after like 2 hours!